# Magento modules installed not showing in Magento connect Manager

Tags: magento

Just installed two Magento modules from Yoast, there is an issue with them, they don't show

up in the Magento connect Manager section, they've vanished. Is this normal?

Please help me out guys,

Thank you once again

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short Version: Yes, this is normal.

Long version: First off, some terminology

1. A Module is logic collection of PHP classes and configuration files that are designed to interact with Magento in a specific way.
2. A Magento Connect package is a collection arbitrary PHP file that can be installed into Magento system

A Magento Connect package can contain Modules, but may also contain other PHP files which get installed into your system.

Magento Connect doesn't know **anything** about the Modules that have been installed into your system.  It only knows about packages. If you've installed some Yoast modules, Magento Connect doesn't know anything about them.  This is the normal state of affairs in the Magento ecosystem.

Additionally, many commercial extension vendors have built **their own** package management systems.  For example, before installing an AITOC extension, you need to installed the AITOC installer.

*Self Links Ahoy*: Regarding an admin for installed code modules, I'm trying to get a community run extension for managing them off the ground.  There's [background here](http://alanstorm.com/magento_list_module), and you can (ironically?) install the [Module List Module via Magento Connect](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/alanstorm/extension/6677/module_list).

Comment: Thanks Alan, the module list module looks very useful.

Comment: Hi Alan,
Just installed the module and this error came out in the module list tab:                                                    Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()  in /var/www/vhosts/xxxxxxx.com/httpdocs/app/code/local/Pulsestorm/Modulelist/Model/Report/Infered.php on line 124, what should I do?   Thank you

Comment: That's an odd bug, would you mind adding   var_dump($folder . DS . '*');var_dump($files); at line 124?  I was under the impression glob always returned an array

Answer (score 3):

If you did not install them through the connect manager but just uploaded files they will not show up in Magento Connect Manager.

Answer (score 1):

Please navigate to System>Configuration >Advanced (Left Bottom) and check Disable Modules Output. There list all the installed modules.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the reason why nothing shows up is because magento is a buggy #$@%  *&#$@  #$#$*%)_.

There are so many issues documented regarding Magento Connect, and its downloader.  It does not install your extensions, and it does not tell you why it is not installing your extensions either.  It does not tell you what went wrong, or if it went wrong, and it barely tells you where things went wrong!

It's no wonder people are trying to install their packages manually!
Why should I buy third party extensions to install from Magento connect?

Here are some:

http://www.magentocommerce.com/bug-tracking/issue/index/id/964

[Problem with Magento connect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6044038/problem-with-magento-connect)

[Magento Connect install Error moving uploaded file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14615329/magento-connect-install-error-moving-uploaded-file)

[Magento Connect Manager cannot get package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13947150/magento-connect-manager-cannot-get-package)