# Magento Connect Manager cannot get package

Tags: xml, magento, e-commerce, connect

I tried to install this extension onto my magento store:

http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/facebookfreebelvg-4448.html

The console said it installed fine, but it's nowhere to be found in the admin panel or anywhere in the directories as far as I can tell. I have dug through all the usual spots for XML and module files to be.

Now whenever I go to Magento Connect Manager it says under `Manage Installed Extensions`:

> Cannot get package: 'facebookfreebelvg'

and doesn't show any of my installed extensions.

Where does Magento Connect Manager get the installed extensions information from? I'm leaning towards the fact it's added the info into an xml somewhere but none of the files actually exist.

I tried reloading a backup I made of the downloader but it's still saying it, so I don't think it's in the downloader folder anywhere.

Alternatively, is there a way to force a reinstall of an extension?

Comment: try to refresh your cache. Admin -> System -> Cache Management

Comment: Tried that, cache is up to date. Thanks though!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After messing with permissions and looking absolutely everywhere for any leftover files, I decided to write it off. The downloader is implemented badly, if you ask me.

I'm just installing all my extensions manually, now. I prefer it that way, anyway.

Thanks for the help, everyone.

Answer (score 1):

If the extension was downloaded, it should be in the hidden directory

> downloader/.cache/community/

Otherwise try using connect to install it on a fresh development version of Magento and then copying the files across from the downloaded/.cache directory as per a manual install.

p.s. don't forget to log out and log back in.