# Magento Connect install "Error moving uploaded file"

Tags: magento

I have a problem with Magento connect. I am not able to install any downloaded packages of Magento extensions like MailChimp, OneStep checkout package.

While I am uploading the package, it shows this error:

> Error moving uploaded file

How do I fix it?

Comment: Did you check the owner/permission of your magento files (app, skin etc)?

Comment: Yes, I found solution. i have given 777 for Var folder of magento.. its now working fine. Thanks

Comment: 777 is too open, you should use 666 as Magento recommends here http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/1_-_installation_and_configuration/installing_magento_via_shell_ssh

Comment: Be sure you `chmod o+w -R var media` and then `chmod o+w app/etc`. Your permissions should really be 755 for directories and 644 for files (depending on your server config) which you can do via the fine command over SSH. `find . -type d -print -exec chmod 755 {} \;` and ind . -type f -print -exec chmod 644 {} \;` and then run the `chmod` command listed above. Alternatively, you can install extensions via FTP if you click on the settings tab if the problem persists! This is an easier solution!

Answer (score 0):

The solution to this problem is to set all folders permission to 777.

Go to your installation root folder and run the following command (You should have access to SSH on your server to run this command):-

```
find . -type d -exec chmod 777 {} \;
```

Now you will not get the error on Magento Connect Manager and you will be able to install any extension from there.

Don’t forget to change the folder permission to 755 after you are done with installing your extension from Magento Connect Manager.

To do this, run the following commands:-

```
find . -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;
chmod 777 var var/.htaccess app/etc
find var -type d -exec chmod 777 {} \;
chmod -R 777 media
```